# How to find $r_4/r_1$?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Four circles are drawn. Let $A_1,$ $A_2,$ $A_3,$ $A_4$ be the areas of the regions, so $A_1$ is the area inside the smallest circle, $A_2$ is the area outside the smallest circle and inside the second-smallest circle, and so on. The areas satisfy
$$A_1 = \frac{A_2}{2} = \frac{A_3}{3} = \frac{A_4}{4}$$Let $r_1$ denote the radius of the smallest circle, and let $r_4$ denote the radius of the largest circle. Find $\frac{r_4}{r_1}.$

[image: Four circles]

Comment: More information is needed. Are the circles concentric?

Comment: the circles aren't concentric

Comment: I added a link to the picture

Answer (score 2):

The area within the fourth circle is: $A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4=A_1+2A_1+3A_1+4A_1=10A_1$, so the ratio of areas between circle 4 and 1 is $\frac{10A_1}{A_1}=10$, therefore the ratio between radii is $\sqrt{10}$.